# Harmonic Balance works, transient does not work!

Tags: simulation, transient, harmonics

I have an oscillator circuit and the harmonic balance simulation shows there is oscillation in Vout:
[image]

However, when I run a transient analysis, the results are totally different and show there is no oscillation in my frequency range:
[image]

Why is there such a huge difference? Which one is right?
The circuit in the harmonic balance is the following, using the Modified Colpitts Core of the ADS Keysight suite:
[image]

The circuit in the transient analysis is the following:
[image]

Comment: Include the circuit and simulator setup. What simulation result do **you** expect from **your** circuit? I think it is silly to simulate a "black box" (you don't reveal your circuit) and then you ask us which one is correct? Proper use of a simulator is as follows: You **think about** what the result should be, then you simulate. If the results don't match, assume that your assumption (of how the circuit works) is wrong or that you didn't use the simulator properly. I can make a simulator do all kinds of weird things by simply **using it in the wrong way**.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have added my circuit!

Comment: Without going through your circuit in detail (it looks a bit "uncommon") - are youaware that the principle of harmonic balance works only under the condition that the feedback path has a very large selectivity (sufficient damping of higher harmonics)?

Comment: Maybe try drawing a regular circuit and not use the odd looking and blurry image from your (ahem) simulation tool. A simple circuit without all the mush i.e. a circuit with component values and component references is needed. I mean who knows what a "modified colpitts core" actually is?